# Hamburger menu on bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how to create a hamburger menu for this code?

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="collapse  d-md-flex h-100 box">
          <ul class="nav flex-column flex-nowrap h-100">
            <li class="nav-item h-25"><a class="nav-link h-100 " href="#">A </a></li>
            <li class="nav-item h-25 "><a class="nav-link h-100  " href="#">B</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item h-25"><a class="nav-link h-100 " href="#l">C</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item h-25"><a class="nav-link h-100" href="#">D</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: follow the documentation for it : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Use the Navbar toggler: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/

Comment: You also need to use bootstrap's javascript. The link is available here: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should [follow the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/). Your code should look like this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">A</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">B</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">C</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">D</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```